# Git and github for beginner

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and I'm having a hard time uploading my projects to github, and I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm opening a repo in github and then I'm running these commands:

```
git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Users/*****/Desktop/****/projects/100-prisoners/.git/
PS C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\projects\100-prisoners>  git add .
PS C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\projects\100-prisoners> git commit -m "add files"
[master bdf366c] add files
 1 file changed, 19 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 100-prisoners/100-prisoners.py
PS C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\projects\100-prisoners>  git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 693 bytes | 693.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://github.com/idogross1/100-prisoners.git
   53ef809..bdf366c  master -> master
```

After I enter these commands, I see in Github that

> master had recent pushes 5 minutes ago

but when I'm trying to pull, I see

> There isn’t anything to compare. main and master are entirely different commit histories.

Hope you can help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: The repo's main branch on GitHub is called "main". You have been working on a branch called "master".

What are you trying to pull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the answer from Arko Abir and the comment from CodeCaster, it looks like you are not only working on a separate branch, but also have initialized your repository multiple times. I can reproduce your problem if I do something like this:

1. Create new repo from the github GUI
2. Initialize a repo from the command line and push changes:

```
➜  git init
➜  echo "# test-repo" >> README.md
➜  git add README.md
➜  git commit -m "add files"
[master (root-commit) b7f9782] add files
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README.md
➜  git remote add origin https://github.com/will-gerard/test-repo.git
➜  git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 228 bytes | 228.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/will-gerard/test-repo.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

At this point there is one branch, "master," with one commit on it, commit b7f9782.

In order to get the message you mention, "There isn't anything to compare..." I can initialize a new git repo. Running git init again will find the .git directory created the first time, and reinitialize the existing repo. If this file is deleted, a new repo will be initialized: (note that this is a hidden file, use `ls -a` to view it)

```
➜  rm -rf .git
➜  git init
➜  git remote add origin https://github.com/will-gerard/test-repo.git
➜  git checkout -b main
➜  git add .
➜  git commit -m "first commit on main" 
➜  git push origin main
```

Now the repo has a separate branch, also with one commit, but it is a different commit than the one which exists on the first branch. In other words, the git histories of the two branches are completely separate. Now when we look at the repo on github.com, and select the "compare and pull request" link, we can see your error message, because the two branches, main and master, have entirely separate git histories, since the repository was initialized multiple times.

I assume you didn't delete the .git repo like I did for this test, but is it possible you initialized once in the gui and once locally? Or twice locally but in different directories, and then pushed to separate branches in the same repo? When you create a new repository on Github.com and do not select the option to create a README file, they show instructions for how to add an initial commit in a few different ways. I recommend picking one of these methods and making sure to only initialize the repository once. Or, what I think is even simpler, is to select the option to add a readme file when creating the repo. This will create an initial commit for you. Then you can create a fresh directory on your machine, clone the repository locally with `git clone <link to repo>,` copy your files into this directory, and commit+push them upstream. This way there is no manual `git init` required.

Answer (score -1):

```
git fetch origin 
git checkout master
```

now you can pull your master main issue is you are in main branch but you are trying to pull master branch. By default git create main branch now.